# Size on bundle vs. size on disk. Also, minified and gzipped

Tags: npm, node-modules

I find it hard to understand all these different sizes for npm packages. What's the difference between the "size on disk" and the "size on bundle"? Also, what's a "minified size", and when does npm use gzip? Thank you.